# There are multiple Bootstrap Tables on a single page. How can we achieve 'fixed header' solution in this situation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap framework v3 and created 4 tables on a single page. Two in one container.

e.g.
First Container:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"> <table> <thead></thead> <tbody></tbody> </table> </div> // first table
<div class="col-md-6"> <table> <thead></thead> <tbody></tbody> </table> </div> // second table
</div>
</div>
```

Second Container:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"> <table> <thead></thead> <tbody></tbody> </table> </div> // third table
<div class="col-md-6"> <table> <thead></thead> <tbody></tbody> </table> </div> // fourth table
</div>
</div>
```

I'd searched the internet and tried lot of codes but headers of all the four tables on a single page are not fixing right as they should be.

I want all the four headers and captions to be fixed while the body of the table to be scroll-able both vertically and horizontally for a given height and a width.

**Working Demo:** Go to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a6jY3w) and launch preview in a separate window.

Comment: If you could include a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example or a working example here, that would be useful. I don't quite understand what you're saying and it'd be nice to see any css that you are using.

Comment: Table behaves weird with different browsers when uses both V/H Scroll. The best option could be fix the table header width and use ellipsis with tootip if data exceeds and use only vertical scroll with fix header.

Comment: @Adam0410 Go to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a6jY3w) and launch preview in a separate window.

Comment: @user3200474 : Add Parent Class / ID then you can add specific Styles